# Tracking down error reports

Tags: bug-reporting

I've recently started using Ubuntu 17.04 and it's asking me to send a lot of error reports. I want to help Ubuntu find and fix whatever issues arise, so I submit most of them. The message boxes look like this:

[image]

After I submit these, is there a way to track down the relevant error/bug report at the [Error Tracker](https://errors.ubuntu.com/)? I want to see if my issues are getting fixed, or if they maybe need more details.